# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 at Generator.main(Generator.java:35)

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Generator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        int scorehome = 0;
        int scoreaway = 0;
        int invalid = 0;
        int goals = 0;
        int valid = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Results.txt")); // create a scanner which scans from a file

        String line;    // stores the each line of text read from the file

        while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();  // read the next line of text from the file

            //split the line
            String [] elements = line.split(":");

            //System.out.println("Element " + (i+1) + " was : " + elements[i]);
            if (elements.length < 4) {                  
                String home = elements[0].trim();
                String away = elements[1].trim();
                String homescore = elements[2].trim();
                String awayscore = elements[3].trim();

                boolean homescoreVal = false;
                boolean awayscoreVal = false;
                boolean homenameVal = false;
                boolean awaynameVal = false;

                try {   // "try" is a special statement which allows us to deal with "exceptions"
                    scorehome = Integer.parseInt(homescore);    // attempt to convert the String into an Integer type value
                    homescoreVal = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    homescoreVal = false;
                }
                try {
                    scoreaway = Integer.parseInt(awayscore);    // attempt to convert the String into an Integer type value
                    awayscoreVal = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    homescoreVal = false;
                }

                if (home.length() <= 1) {
                    homenameVal = false;
                } else {
                    homenameVal = true;
                }

                if (away.length() <= 1) {
                    awaynameVal = false;
                } else {
                    awaynameVal = true;
                }

                if (homescoreVal == true && awayscoreVal == true
                        && homenameVal == true && awaynameVal == true){ 

                    System.out.println(home + " [" + scorehome + "] | "
                            + away + " [" + scoreaway + "]\r");

                    goals = (scorehome + scoreaway) + goals;

                    valid = 1 + valid;
                } else {
                    invalid = 1 +invalid;
                }

            } else {
                invalid = 1 + invalid;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\rValid match was " + valid
                + ", total goals scored was " + goals);
        System.out.println("Invalid match count was " + invalid + ".");

        System.out.println("\nEOF");    // Output and End Of File message.

    }
}
```

I seem to get a resource leak saying my scanner is never closed and my `import java.lang.reflect.Array;` is never used. Any ideas on how I can fix either of these two problems and why it's happening?

Comment: i'm confused on what your saying?

Comment: Which line is line 35? Most of us won't be copy-pasting your code into a text editor.

Comment: Which line in the above source code is the 35th line in the source code as the error indicates that the error is on line 35. Which is line 35?

Comment: String awayscore = elements[3].trim(); is line 35 sorry

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to change

```
        if (elements.length < 4) {
            String home = elements[0].trim();
            String away = elements[1].trim();
            String homescore = elements[2].trim();
            String awayscore = elements[3].trim();
```

to

```
        if (elements.length >= 4) {
            String home = elements[0].trim();
            String away = elements[1].trim();
            String homescore = elements[2].trim();
            String awayscore = elements[3].trim();
```

since you are relying on at least 4 elements to exist in the `elements` array (when you try to access `elements[3]`).

Comment: the program needs to make sure that there are exactly 4 elements though and if not it doesnt show the reults

Comment: @JackHumphreys If you want exactly 4 elements, change the condition to `elements.length == 4`

Answer (score 0):

When you are done with the Scanner instance, call scanner.close().  And just erase the Array import; you don't use it, so it is unnecessary.